# Using a 3V latching relay to power up ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, power

I'm trying to use a 2-Coil Latching Relay like [TXS2SA-L2-3V](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=255-2347-5-ND) for  powering up a ESP8266. My idea is to activate the relay by setting the first coil to high and deactivate the coil by setting the second coil to high. In my circuit i will set the second coil to high at the end of the code by the esp8266. I need the latching (holding the power) function of it. Because when somebody activtes the Deep Sleep function to early, I have no electricity to power the esp8266.

My question is:

What kind of circuit I must use? I have no idea where I can start.

I have a regulator that can be enabled via de EN signal.

Thanks in advance!

[image: TPS61200 regulator]

Comment: I've read your question twice, but it's still unclear to me what your actual question is.

Comment: `My idea is to activate the relay by setting the first coil to high`...? How?

Comment: `deactivate the coil by setting the second coil to high.` ...? How?

Comment: You control a latching relay of this sort in the exact same way as a normal relay. What is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You use a latching relay of this form in the exact same way as a normal relay - it's just there's two of them.

One coil you want to control with a button (power on) and the other with a transistor (and possibly an "off" button as well).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYlxPM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Press ON to latch the relay into the ON position (NO -> COM). Activate M1 or press OFF to latch the relay into the OFF position (NC -> COM).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for your help. What kind of transistor can I use? Both ESP8266 and the relay work with 3V3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If use an n MOSFET with a VGS below 2v.

Comment: I have great luck with the IRLZ44N on 8266s; cheap w/low rds+vgsth